# Dev Express grid column headings - can they reduce?

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I have a dev express grid, i changed size from 100% to 42% because my data is very short.
One question, the column headings, essentially dictate the size of the data col. is there a way to reduce the font size on only 1 col, so that a Y/N type of data would not be too large.

```
dx:ASPxGridView ID="gvD_CW" ClientInstanceName="gvD_CW" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="LDSD_CW"
        KeyFieldName="ID" OnHtmlRowCreated="gvD_CW_HtmlRowCreated" Width="42%" SettingsBehavior-AllowGroup="true"
        SettingsPager-PageSize="20" OnCustomCallback="gvD_CW_CustomCallback">
        <Settings ShowFilterRow="false" ShowFilterRowMenu="true" ShowGroupPanel="True" ShowFooter="True" />
        <SettingsBehavior AllowSort="false" />
        <SettingsPager>
            <PageSizeItemSettings Visible="true" Items="10, 20, 50" />
        </SettingsPager>
        <Columns>
```

Comment: You have not posted full code..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this

```
<Columns>
    <dxg:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="YesNo" Width="100" VisibleIndex="3" >
        <HeaderStyle Wrap="True"/>
    </dxg:GridViewDataColumn>
</Columns>
```

The ASPxGridView control resizes its columns to display its text. If a total column width is wider than a grid's width, the grid's width is also increased up to the page's width.
You can use

```
ColumnMinWidth - specifies the minimum width of grid columns.
MinWidth - specifies the minimum width of the current column.
```